# Python and pyodbc with SQL Server. How do I get decimal data from SQL Server when the precision increases?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a SQL Server database table with two columns `f1` & `f2`. These are defined in SQL Server as

```
f1 DECIMAL (10, 4)
f2 DECIMAL (13, 4)
```

When I select using python and pyodbc and loading the data with :

```
(select f1 , f2 from table where condition) 
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

I am not getting the correct data for `f2`.

Data reports `f1` as `Decimal('16.7300')` which is correct.

`f2` in the database has a value of 40.000, but the query is returning `Decimal('0.0000')`.

```
(Decimal('16.7300'), Decimal('0.0000'))
```

I have tried a cast on the query

```
cast(f2 as decimal(13,4))
```

but the query is still returning 0.

Can anyone advise how to return the correct value from the database please?

In reply to @Panagiotis Kanavos here is the exact code.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver ='{SQL Server}', server = 'ServerName', database = 'db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = '''select f1 , f2 from dbo.Table where Company = 'Acme' '''
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchone()
print (data)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with pyodbc 4.0.26 and msodbcsql17.dll version 17.03.0001. For me, `print(crsr.execute("SELECT f1, f2 FROM t1 WHERE id = 1").fetchone())` produces `(Decimal('16.7300'), Decimal('40.0000'))`

Comment: What is the *actual* code you used? Most likely the problem is the query itself, eg an integer division. If there was such a critical error in pyodbc or SQL Server, people would have noticed

Comment: @GordThompson.  I have updated to msodbcsql17.dll, and this seems to have resolved the issue.  Thank you.